# jQuery.load(function(){}) event doesn't work in collab with .get()?

Tags: jquery, get, load

So I have this script on a website i'm working on, which basically loads images from a database and puts them in a div. When all the images are loaded, I want it to fire a scroller plugin (smoothdivscroll). But I can't find a way to make the last part work.

Here is the code:

```
$.get("pages/photosgigs.php", { gig: $(this).attr("id")}, function(data) {
    $('#makeMeScrollableGall').html(data)
    $(window).load( function() {
        $("#makeMeScrollableGall").smoothDivScroll();
        resize();
    });
});
```

The php script on photosgigs.php returns a simple `<img class="photo" src="..." />`. I've also tried it with `$("img.photo").load()` which, although I know it would fire when the first image is loaded, also doesn't work. Also tried `$("#makeMeScrollableGall").load()`, doesn't work either.

I'm beginning to think my problem lies in the fact that my images are loaded dynamically. Is this correct?

Or am I just doing everything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `window.onload` is rarely ever what you'll want here.  The `onload` event fires **once** when the page *first* loads, it won't fire again...so currently you're adding a listener for an event that's already fired and won't fire again.  Instead use the `load` event on the image *and* check that it hasn't already fired (which it might have, if it's loading from cache).

Those changes would look like this:

```
$.get("pages/photosgigs.php", { gig: $(this).attr("id") }, function(data) {
  //load data, find the photo we just added
  $('#makeMeScrollableGall').html(data).find('img.photo').load(function() {
    //when the load event fires for the image, run this
    $("#makeMeScrollableGall").smoothDivScroll();
    resize();
  //loop through the loaded images (just one) but this is easier
  }).each(function() { 
     //if the image was already loaded (cached) fire the load event above
     if(this.complete) $(this).load(); 
  });
});
```

The `.complete` is checking if the image is already loaded, if it is then fire our event handler just bound by calling [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (shortcut for [`.trigger('load")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)).

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Is there any way to know when the last image is loaded?

Comment: Yes, but how am I supposed to get the length while I'm loading the images? The way I see it now is: Get 1 image from server - fire load event - Get 1 image from server - fire lo.. How do I know beforehand how many images I'm loading?

Comment: @scipicore - You don't...that's what the `.length` check is for.  I think a full example would be much clearer here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QV9RS/  Does that help? :)